# Integration task problem

Tags: integration

$$\int_{0}^{+\infty }\frac{x \log(x)}{(x^{2}+1)^{2}}dx$$

I need to find out does it converge?
And if answer is yes, what is value?

I got this as a task on my exam.
I come till the end and i can't resolve with 0

Comment: $dx$ is missing!

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner My apologies

Comment: You sure there exists a primitive?

Comment: this integral is divergent

Comment: Maple says this here $$1/2\,\ln  \left( x \right) \ln  \left( -i \left( -x+i \right) 
 \right) +1/2\,\ln  \left( x \right) \ln  \left( -i \left( x+i
 \right)  \right) +1/4\,{\it dilog} \left( {x}^{2}+1 \right) 
$$

Comment: On this site, questions that merely state an isolated problem are often put on hold. You can improve the question by including motivation and context. Where did you encounter the problem? Why is it of interest? What have you tried already? Where did you get stuck? You can edit the question to include that information.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner are you sure? :/

Comment: see additionally here https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20x*log(x)%2F(1%2Bx%5E2)%20for%20x%3D0%20to%20infinity

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner: Err there is nothing wrong with Paolo's answer and besides WA also says 0 and even gives an anti-derivative (`http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+x*ln%28x%29%2F%28x^2%2B1%29^2+from+0+to+infinity`)

Comment: @user21820 thank you :D

Answer (score 4):

The integral is $0$. On the one hand
$$
\int_1^{\infty}\frac{x\ln x}{(x^2+1)^2}dx<\int_1^\infty \frac{x^2}{x^4}dx < \infty.
$$
On the other hand
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{x\ln x}{(x^2+1)^2}dx=\int_\infty^1\frac{-\ln t}{t (t^{-2}+1)^2}\frac{1}{-t^2}dt=-\int_1^\infty\frac{t\ln t}{(t^2+1)^2}dt.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=\tan y$

$$I=\int_0^\infty\dfrac{x\ln x}{(1+x^2)^2}dx=\dfrac12\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin2y\ln(\tan y)dy$$

Using $\displaystyle\int_a^bf(y)\ dy=\int_a^bf(a+b-y)\ dy,$

$$2I=\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin2y\ln(\tan y)dy=\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin2y\ln(\cot y)dy$$

$$2I+2I=\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin2y\{\ln(\tan y)+\ln(\cot y)\}dy$$

But $\ln(\tan y)+\ln(\cot y)=\ln\{\tan y\cdot\cot y\}=?$